# Sequelize bulkCreate controller not inserting into associated table

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, associations

I am trying to insert multiple records into 2 associated tables/models using sequelize bulkCreate. I can only get data to insert into the parent table. I am using MVC framework.

I have each model in a separate file, with associations defined therein.

The function to carry out the bulkCreate is in a separate controller file.

I call the request using a route file.

Here are the models and the model index

Occurrence.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Occurrence = sequelize.define("occurrence", {
        recordedBy : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull : true
            },
        scientificName : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull : true
            }
    });

    Occurrence.associate = (models) => {
        Occurrence.hasMany(models.materialSample, {
            foreignKey: 'occurrenceTableID'
        })
    }
    
    return Occurrence;
};
```

MaterialSample.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const MaterialSample = sequelize.define("materialSample", {
        materialSampleID : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull : true
        },
        materialSampleType : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull : true
        }
        numberCollected : {
            type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull : true
        }
    });

    MaterialSample.associate = (models) => {
        MaterialSample.belongsTo(models.occurrence, {
            foreignKey: 'occurrenceTableID'
        })
    }
    return MaterialSample;
};
```

index.js

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const { response } = require("express");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.project = require("./Project.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.event = require("./Event.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.occurrence = require("./Occurrence.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.materialSample = require("./MaterialSample.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.preservedSpecimen = require("./PreservedSpecimen.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.transfer = require("./Transfer.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.germplasmViabilityTest = require("./GermplasmViabilityTest.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.viabilityTracking = require("./ViabilityTracking.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);


//set up table associations
Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]){
    //call the associate function and pass reference to all other models
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

module.exports = db;
```

Here is the controller file with the bulkCreate function (insertData.js)

```
const db = require("../models");
const MaterialSample = db.materialSample;
const Occurrence = db.occurrence;

async function insertData() {
  //create some data
  const data = [
    {
      recordedBy: "Botanist One",
      MaterialSamples:
        {
          materialSampleType: "tissue",
          numberCollected: 2
        }
    },
    {
      recordedBy: "Botanist Two",
      MaterialSamples:
      {
        materialSampleType: "seed",
        numberCollected: 72
      }
    }
  ]

  //use bulkCreate with include to insert the data
  const result = await Occurrence.bulkCreate(data, {
    include : [
      {
        model: MaterialSample
      }
    ]
  })

}

module.exports = {
  insertData
}
```

and the route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const insertDatasController= require("../controllers/insertData")



let routes = (app) => {
 
  //views
    //index
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render("index");
    });

  //POST /api/materialSamples
  router.post("/materialSample", insertDataController.insertData)

  app.use("/api", router);
};

module.exports = routes;
```

Both records are inserted into the occurrence table, but nothing gets inserted into the materialSample table.

I will also note that when I send POST the request via PostMan, it seems to hang in "Sending request..."

Comment: Did you check if `MaterialSamples` props should `materialSamples` and an array instead of an object?

Comment: As for hanging POST - you should return something in a response using `res.send` or `res.json`

Comment: ahh of course! Thanks it should have been materialSamples. I was so caught up on plural or not, I missed the capitalization. and yes, res.send/res.json/res.status fixes the hang. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it. it was the capitalization of the table name in the controller function

```js
async function insertData(req, res) {
  //create some data
  const data = [{
      recordedBy: "Botanist One",
      materialSamples: {
        materialSampleType: "tissue",
        numberCollected: 2
      }
    },
    {
      recordedBy: "Botanist Two",
      materialSamples: {
        materialSampleType: "seed",
        numberCollected: 72
      }
    }
  ]
  //use bulkCreate with include to insert the data
  const result = await Occurrence.bulkCreate(data, {
      include: [{
        model: MaterialSample
      }]
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.send()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

}
```